# Linux shell scripting - Simple awk script issue

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm trying to do a very simple awk script exercise and cannot figure why it isn't working.

The awk script should be used to only display entries begining with 2012, so given the following input file:

```
  2009 Dec X 29.44
  2009 Dec Y 32.32
  2012 Jan X 321.11
  2012 Feb Y 1.99
  2012 Feb X 32.99
  2012 Mar X 11.45
  2010 Jan X 14.75
  2011 Feb Y 21.00
  2011 Mar X 7.77
```

The output should be as follows:

```
 % awk -f awkscriptfile inputfile
  Data for year 2012
  ==================
  Jan : 321.11
  Feb : 1.99
  Feb : 32.99
  Mar : 11.45
  ===================
  volume for 2012 is: 367.54
  4 records processed
  %
```

However, what I get is this:

```
% awk -f awkscriptfile inputfile
    Data for year 2012
    ==================================
     2009 Dec X 29.44
     2009 Dec Y 32.32
     2012 Jan X 321.11
    Jan  :  321.11
     2012 Feb Y 1.99
    Feb  :  1.99
     2012 Feb X 32.99
    Feb  :  32.99
     2012 Mar X 11.45
    Mar  :  11.45
     2010 Jan X 14.75
     2011 Feb Y 21.00
     2011 Mar X 7.77
    ==================================
    volume for 2012 is: $sum
    $count records processed
%
```

**So the awk script is obviously printing out a lot more than it should, and for some reason the sum and count variables aren't being printed.**

This is my code for the awk script:

```
BEGIN {
 print "Data for year 2012"
 print "=================================="
 count = 0
 sum = 0
}
$1 ~ /2012/ {
 print $2, " : ", $4
 count++
 sum += $4
}
END {
 print "=================================="
 print "volume for 2012 is: $sum"
 print "$count records processed"
}
```

From everything I'm looking at for reference, I see no reason why this code shouldn't work. Hopefully someone else can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That exact input and that exact script are not doing that here. Are you sure that's the script you are using **exactly**? Because that looks a lot like the output you would get with a stray truth-y pattern or a debugging `{print}` action.

Comment: Also, you don't use `$` on variables and they don't interpolate in strings. So those last two lines want to be `print "volume for 2012 is : "sum` and `print count " records processed"`.

Comment: I actually had a comment at the top of the script begining with "//" instead of "#", and changing that seems to have fixed it. I thought both worked with shell scripts, but I guess not. And the variable fix you offered of course worked too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awk is not the shell; they are two different things.  They do share their comment syntax with each other as well as many other UNIX utilities, however.   I'm trying to think of any programming language that mixes shell-style `#` comments with C++-style `//` comments, and none is springing to mind..

Comment: And `//` does not work in bash either... possibly csh though I suppose. And yes, `//` is a regex that matches anything and as such will run a default action to print the line (though I'm surprised the rest of your comment didn't cause problems but I suppose awk just saw the words as blank variables or something.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v y="2012" '$1==y{a[NR]=$2":"$4;s+=$4;c++}
    END{line="===================";
    printf "Data for year %s\n%s\n",y,line;
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(a[i])print a[i]
    printf "%s\nvolume for %s is: %.2f\n%d records processed\n", line, y, s, c}' file
```

with your data, it outputs:

```
Data for year 2012
===================
Jan:321.11
Feb:1.99
Feb:32.99
Mar:11.45
===================
volume for 2012 is: 367.54
4 records processed
```

Answer (score 1):

***Here is modified version of your script***

**Input**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat infile
  2009 Dec X 29.44
  2009 Dec Y 32.32
  2012 Jan X 321.11
  2012 Feb Y 1.99
  2012 Feb X 32.99
  2012 Mar X 11.45
  2010 Jan X 14.75
  2011 Feb Y 21.00
  2011 Mar X 7.77
```

**Script**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat stat_data.awk
BEGIN{

    if( ARGC < 2 || year=="")
    {
        error=1
        print "\n\t\tUsage   : awk -vyear=<year> -f script.awk <input file>"
        print "\t\tExample : awk -vyear=2012 -f script.awk test.txt\n"
        exit
    }

        print "Data for year "year
        print "=================================="

}
$1==year{
        print $2":"$4
        sum+=$4
        count++
}
END{
     if(!error)
     {
        print "=================================="
        print "volume for "year" is: "sum
        print count" records processed"
     }
}
```

**How to execute ?**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ awk -vyear=2012 -f stat_data.awk  infile
```

**Output**

```
Data for year 2012
==================================
Jan:321.11
Feb:1.99
Feb:32.99
Mar:11.45
==================================
volume for 2012 is: 367.54
4 records processed
```